# Custom status message on a Views page

Tags: views, theming, routes, emails

I have different urls :

- domain.com/blog : a list of articles made with Views module
- domain.com/blog/article-title : article alias
- domain.com/newsletter/confirm/add/xyz/ok : confirmation link sent to new subscribers by email by Simplenews module
- domain.com/blog/ok : page to which subscribers are redirected after they click the confirmation link (simplenews passes the last arg to the redirect page)

For now, domain.com/blog/ok returns the same as /blog or a 404 (if I set the Global:null contextual filter in Views). I'd like new subscribers to be redirected to the blog page **with a custom status message** (for instance "You're now subscribed").

I guess it's something with hook_menu ? or MYTHEME_preprocess_page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone's interested, I finally got it fixed implementing a simplenews hook :

```
function MY_MODULE_simplenews_subscribe_user() {
  drupal_get_messages('status'); // Flush default simplenews status message
  drupal_set_message(t('My custom message'), 'status'); // Set my own message
}
```